# Chrome blocking insecure content from relative URL

Tags: .net, url, google-chrome, iis, https

I've taken over the development of a site and Chrome is blocking URLs which use relative paths  with the message that they are served under http when the page is https.

The head of [the page](https://www.universalmetals.com/inventory/bitsnpeices.rails) is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/cart.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/inventory.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.4" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=2.0.4" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web-app/css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.4" media="screen">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/jquery.animate_from_to-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/cart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-app/js/inventory.js"></script>
```

Shouldn't a relative url pick up https? Is this a caching issue? My background is 'nix/open source so I have don't have much experience with IIS, is there a server setting that can force https for all resources?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be adding a path in Web.config:

```
<secureWebPages mode="On" ignoreHandlers="withStandardExtensions">
    <directories>
        <add path="web-app/css" secure="Ignore" recurse="True" />
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the problem, and Chrome is assuming http:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Based on research this was the protocol free way to switch between http and https. And that actually works :) those files are served over https. It's the relative paths that are showing up as http.